# Return entire XML document & doc-uri with embedded triples using Sparql

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have some XML documents with embedded triples.

I can run a sem:sparql query with no issues, but I'm not sure how to return the entire XML document that the embedded triples are in along with the document URI with the results. Thanks in advance

Does anyone know how to do this ?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics"  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $res := sem:sparql('
  SELECT ?country
  WHERE {
    <http://example.org/news/Nixon> <http://example.org/wentTo> ?country
  }
  ',
  (),
  (),
  cts:and-query( (

    cts:or-query( (
      cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), "AP Newswire" ),
      cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), "BBC" )
   ) )
 ) )
)


return $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner way (with less casting) but this is how I have done it before in XQuery :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 

import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
      at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $triples := sem:sparql('
SELECT *
WHERE
{ ?subject ?predicate ?object }
')

return sem:database-nodes($triples ! sem:triple(map:get(., "subject"), map:get(., "predicate"), map:get(., "object"))) ! fn:base-uri(.)
```

Comment: Interesting.  This only works if you have the subject, predicate, and object though right ?

If I select only the subject for example, I'm not sure it will be able to get the database nodes

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp Yes, as far as I know you need a full sem:triple object for sem:database-nodes. However, it shouldn't be hard to build that since you have specified the missing subject and predicate in your query. Alternatively, you could include your document URI in your triples and link the other triples to it so you could figure this out in SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by doing the it this way. I hope this helps someone else. It took me a solid 5+ hours of reading through MarkLogic documentation. I think I have a good handle on it all now. 
  I'm not sure this is the fastest way, but it only took 93ms

```
for $id in  sem:query-results-serialize(  $rez  , 'xml')//s:uri/text()
          return   
  xdmp:node-uri( (cts:search(/blah//sem:triple/*[text() = $id ]  , ()))[1]    )
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("sem:subject"), $id), 'unfiltered') . You could expand cts:element-value-query to a cts:or-query to cover subject, predicate and object if needed.

Comment: I thought using  some xpath expression as the 1st parameter would be faster, since I'm specifying the document root node (filtering the set of possible documents).
Is that incorrect ?

Comment: Specifying the document root node can potentially be quick, but mostly when it rules out most of the documents. `//` is actually expensive in most cases. XPath could also forces filtering of results to apply document ordering, though not entirely sure if that is also the case with search paths. There are usually many factors that influence performance. Best is to measure, and keep measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`cts:triple-range-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:triple-range-query). It can be used in `cts:search` directly, and blended into your other query. It allows looking for individual triples only, though your example is fairly simple.

To find all AP Newswire and BBC reports talking about Nixon visiting countries:

```
query version "1.0-ml";

for $doc in cts:search(
  collection(),
  cts:and-query( (
    cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), ("AP Newswire", "BBC") ),
    cts:triple-range-query(
      sem:iri("http://example.org/news/Nixon"),
      sem:iri("http://example.org/wentTo"),
      ()
    )
  ) )
)[1 to 10]
return (xdmp:node-uri($doc), $doc)
```

You can also pre-execute a SPARQL to resolve more complex SPARQL queries first, and feed the result into a cts:search with a triple-range-query. For example: to find all reports about specific countries visited by Nixon (as reported by AP Newswire and BBC):

```
let $countries := sem:sparql('
  SELECT DISTINCT ?country
  WHERE {
    <http://example.org/news/Nixon> <http://example.org/wentTo> ?country
  }
  ',
  (),
  (),
  cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("source"), ("AP Newswire", "BBC") )
) ! map:get(., "country")

for $doc in cts:search(
  collection(),
  cts:triple-range-query(
    sem:iri("http://example.org/news/Nixon"),
    sem:iri("http://example.org/wentTo"),
    $country[1 to 3]
  )
)[1 to 10]
return (xdmp:node-uri($doc), $doc)
```

Note the subtle differences between the above two examples..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, my SPARQL queries are more complex than the one I gave so I can try your pre-executed query example. It seems like MarkLogic would already have the document when its doing the cts:element-value-query() in the SPARQL query, so an additional cts:search seems odd to me.  I wish there was a way to extract the node-uri when it already has the doc

Comment: There is some doc awareness during SPARQL, but since the same triple can originate from multiple documents, doc awareness is lost in the sem bindings that are returned. Hence the double pass, but since it resolves from indexes, you hardly notice..

Comment: Small addition to my last comment: cts:element-value-query is not resolved by pulling up the actual document, it is resolved from the so-called Universal Index. MarkLogic tries to resolve as much as possible from indexes, which contain references to document fragments. The actual documents are not retrieved until data within is used or returned. That is postponed until the `[1 to 10]` bit in my examples..